# deciphering the amsco cipher

Tags: math, cryptography

i have successfully implemented a programme to convert plaintext to cipher text for the [amsco cipher] (http://www.thonky.com/kryptos/amsco-cipher/) . However i am not able to get how to go about for converting the cipher text to plain text. How do we determine the length of columns (or number of rows for each column) which converting the cipher to plain text ?
E.g  if the cipher text is  *EMAAE HUMBA LMNRE AUDSR RTSUN WHAVP TOEMH KITVE DGEUS TEATO SHOSO YHNME EKLAI* and the column key is 35142 then under column '1' the start letter is E and next row in the same column would be MA. The third row in column number '1' will have 'A' and so on. However how do we determine the total number of rows for each column ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way, i think, is to just write a loop that does what you did to encode.  so it adds up 1s and 2s for each column until there are no letters left.

here's a program that decodes the text to show what i mean (it's written in python 3):

```
words = ['EMAAE', 'HUMBA', 'LMNRE', 'AUDSR', 'RTSUN', 'WHAVP', 
         'TOEMH', 'KITVE', 'DGEUS', 'TEATO', 'SHOSO', 'YHNME', 'EKLAI']

ctext = ''.join(words)
l = len(ctext)
print('\ntotal chars', l)

key = '35142'
n = len(key)
print('\nkey length', n)

# here we do exactly the same as what you did to encode, except we just
# count the letters.  so chars[x] is the number of characters in column x,
# which starts at 0 and is added 1 or 2 on each line.
chars = [0] * n
remaining = l
ichar = 0
chunk = 0
while remaining > 0:
    k = min(chunk+1, remaining)
    chars[ichar] += k
    remaining -= k
    ichar = (ichar + 1) % n  # this indexes the columns 0..n-1,0..n-1,...
    chunk = (chunk + 1) % 2  # this goes 0,1,0,1,... and we +1 above

# now we have the number of characters in each column, so display that
print('\nkey digit and number of characters')
for i, digit in enumerate(key):
    print(digit, chars[i])

# but the ordering in the encrypted data is different, so we re-order to
# match that.  this uses a bit of a trick in python - if we order a list of
# pairs (a,b) then is it ordered by the first thing in the pair (the key 
# digit) here.  so we order by the key digit, but also re-arrange the
# columns sizes.
digitsandchars = [(digit, chars[i]) for i, digit in enumerate(key)]
print('\nbefore sorting', digitsandchars)
digitsandchars = sorted(digitsandchars)
print('after sorting', digitsandchars)

# now that we have the columns sizes in the right order we can cut up the
# text into the columns
columns = [''] * n
for i in range(n):
    digit, nchars = digitsandchars[i]
    columns[i] = ctext[:nchars]
    ctext = ctext[nchars:]
    print('digit', digit, 'column', columns[i])

# now switch the columns back to the order they were originally
ordered = [columns[int(key[i])-1] for i in range(n)]
print('\nordered columns', ordered)

# and finally we can decode by doing the same process as before - we pick
# off 1 or 2 characters from each column until we have nothing left.
print('\ndecode')
icolumn = 0
remaining = l
chunk = 0
while remaining > 0:
    column = ordered[icolumn]
    k = min(chunk+1, remaining)
    print(column[:k], end='')  # print the first k characters
    remaining -= k
    ordered[icolumn] = column[k:]  # remove the printed characters
    icolumn = (icolumn + 1) % n
    chunk = (chunk + 1) % 2
print()
```

and here's the output:

```
total chars 65

key length 5

key digit and number of characters
3 13
5 14
1 13
4 13
2 12

before sorting [('3', 13), ('5', 14), ('1', 13), ('4', 13), ('2', 12)]
after sorting [('1', 13), ('2', 12), ('3', 13), ('4', 13), ('5', 14)]
digit 1 column EMAAEHUMBALMN
digit 2 column REAUDSRRTSUN
digit 3 column WHAVPTOEMHKIT
digit 4 column VEDGEUSTEATOS
digit 5 column HOSOYHNMEEKLAI

ordered columns ['WHAVPTOEMHKIT', 'HOSOYHNMEEKLAI', 'EMAAEHUMBALMN', 'VEDGEUSTEATOS', 'REAUDSRRTSUN']

decode
WHOEVERHASMADEAVOYAGEUPTHEHUDSONMUSTREMEMBERTHEKAATSKILLMOUNTAINS
```

Comment: no problem - it was fun.  the code isn't super-clear, but i can't see how to write it better, sorry.

Comment: ya but i think there might be some cases where index might be out of range . eg i tried one case here http://ideone.com/xTiBGN

Comment: i had a `5` where i should have had an `n` in the line beginning `ordered = ...`.  code above is fixed.

Comment: Thanks but it does not produce correct result i believe. For the eg in the code http://ideone.com/7XZRbH  it produces the plain text as "IDTRSMOTTHSHORHINNOETISEOURSWIEROBOINEJMAMRRESORN" whereas actually it should have been "RIDERSONTHESTORMINTOTHISHOUSEWEAREBORNJIMMORRISON"

Comment: if you write down the first two lines of that as if you are encoding, you get (R ID E RS O NT H) (ES T OR M IN T OT) so the 1 column (on the right) starts with HOT.  but you have HET at the start of your encrypted text.  so your encrypted text seems to be wrong to me.  i have also written the encryption routine and when i encrypt that text the code above decrypts it.  so either i have misunderstood how the cipher works or your encryption code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tested Andrew's code, and it doesn't seem to work for all cases. Incidentally, I was working on the Amsco cipher quite recently, and there's a rather simple method for decrypting a ciphertext if you know the key:

1. The first step you need to carry out, is to write out the ciphertext into columns as if you were encrypting it
2. Using this format, you then know how many letters must go in each column in the original plain text.
3. You know from your cipher text, that the first one or two letters will go in the column labelled 1. So find this column (remember column 1 may not necessarily be the first column, depending on your key), look at the letter format, and then add in the letters. For example, if you know the format for the column labelled one is:

   AB

   C

   DE

   F

   G

Then you just have to loop through the first seven letters, and add them into column one according to the above format.

4.Repeat this method for the rest of the columns, and then once completed, read the letters row by row, to get the original plain text.

I have the code all working, but there's a competition going on, and one of the tasks involves this cipher. I'll it in in two weeks time.